# Observing a button press with RxPY

Tags: python, rx-py

How can I "listen" to stream of key press events with Python?

I want to do something like this:

```
click_stream.map(lambda k: k.key)
```

But how can I create this `click_stream`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the UI framework, but basically you should:

- create a `Subject`
- call the `Subject.on_next` method in the event callback passing the required args
- subscribe to the `Subject`

you can use the [timeflies](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/examples/timeflies/timeflies_qt.py) example as a guide.